# how to fetch name/key in from datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Couldn't find any existing `Go` specific answer so creating a new one.

Our datastore consist of following columns/attributes

`Name/ID         Email           UserID             UserName`

Now, I want to retrieve these values into my `Go` struct. Here is what i have written

```
type UserDetails struct {
    NameID    string
    Email     string `datastore:"Email"`
    UserID    string `datastore:"UserID"`
    UserName  string `datastore:UserName`
}
```

Now, when i am fetching this entity (based on kind), I am manually setting the `NameID` i.e.,

```
func (c DataStoreClient) GetUserDetailsByOrg(ctx context.Context, orgName string) ([]*UserDetails, error) {
    var userDetails []*UserDetails
    q := datastore.NewQuery(userDetailsKind).
        Namespace(orgName)
    keys, err := c.client.GetAll(ctx, q, &userDetails)
    for i, key := range keys {
        userDetails[i].NameID = key.Name
    }
    return userDetails, err
}
```

Now, the question that i want to ask that is this the correct approach to retrieve `Name/ID` or can i retrieve it by specifying `datastore:Name/ID` in struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [KeyLoader](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#KeyLoader) interface to set the field during entity load.

```
type UserDetails struct {
    NameID   string `datastore:"-"`
    Email    string `datastore:"Email"`
    UserID   string `datastore:"UserID"`
    UserName string `datastore:UserName`
}

func (ud *UserDetails) LoadKey(k *datastore.Key) error {
    ud.NameID = k.Name
    return nil
}

func (ud *UserDetails) Load(ps []datastore.Property) error {
    return datastore.LoadStruct(ud, ps)
}

func (ud *UserDetails) Save() ([]datastore.Property, error) {
    return datastore.SaveStruct(ud)
}
```

Use it like this:

```
func (c DataStoreClient) GetUserDetailsByOrg(ctx context.Context, orgName string) ([]*UserDetails, error) {
    var userDetails []*UserDetails
    q := datastore.NewQuery(userDetailsKind).
        Namespace(orgName)
    _, err := c.client.GetAll(ctx, q, &userDetails)
    return userDetails, err
}
```

The approach in the question works. The advantage of the KeyLoader implementation is that it saves a couple of lines of code wherever the application queries for or gets an entity.

Set the NameID datastore name to "-" so that the property loader and saver ignores the field.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't notice that. actually you have typo there. `p.NameID` should be `ud.NameID`. One more question, so i have separate repo file which has `datastore.client` object. how would `save` method get called from there? I mean the object that i currently have, doesn't have any `datastore` visibility but this code will tie the datastore related code to `repository` and `userdetails` file. you know what i am saying?

Comment: If the destination value for a load operation satisfies the KeyLoader or PropertyLoadSaver interface, then the datastore package calls the methods on those interfaces to load or save the entity  The datastore access code (DatastoreClient in the question) does not need to be in the same package as entity type (UserDetails in the question).

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine. However, because you have NameID without any tag, there will be a datastore entity property with that name set to nothing. It's an unnecessary property to store. So, you could make it "NameID string `datastore:"-"` so datastore ignores it. Alternatively, if you are not exporting this field outside the package or via JSON, you can use a lower case name like "nameID".

Another approach you have is to automatically get the entire key by having a "**key**" field. You can learn more about it in Key Field

https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#hdr-Key_Field